# How is SM712 TVS array suitable for use with MAX485 in an RS485 driver circuit?

Tags: microcontroller, voltage, communication, protection, rs485

I have an RS485 driver circuit consisting of a MAX485 driven by an STM microcontroller. I was looking at TVS diodes for basic protection from electrostatic surges from wiring and handling, and found SM712 being used everywhere.

The MAX485 is powered by a 5V supply rail, and the absolute maximum ratings of the IC specify that the Driver Output and Receiver Input voltages (A, B) should be in the range of -8V to +12.5V.

From the SM712 datasheet, the reverse breakdown voltage is 13.3V which exceeds MAX485's 12.5V. The reverse standoff voltage is 12.0V though.

I'm not use sure if I should go ahead with SM712.

I understand from reading that the standoff voltage is the max voltage at which the diode is guaranteed not to conduct. But I assume that the decision has to be made based on the breakdown voltage.

I also figured that ESD spikes will have very high voltages and the 0.8V difference between the IC's max and the diode's breakdown voltage would be crossed in a matter of microseconds. Perhaps this will not burn the MAX485?

I could use SMBJ series of diodes to get a lower breakdown voltage, but I don't have that kind of real estate on my PCB. I would like to go with SM712 and want to know if it's safe to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from Texas Instruments' [How to Choose a TVS Diode for RS-232, RS-485 and CAN
Based on Voltage Ratings](https://www.ti.com/lit/SSZT891) (sszt891):

> When making a selection, you want VWM to be larger than the recommended operating region of the
> transceiver. As the incoming voltage goes higher, the TVS starts breaking down and conducting more current
> at VBR. But what’s even more important is the highest voltage parameter, VC the clamping voltage under a
> high-current pulse condition. VC represents the maximum clamping voltage with a specific impulse current.

> *When comparing VC to the transceiver parameters, you want to make sure that it doesn’t exceed the absolute
> maximum voltage ratings of the integrated circuit (IC). The “absolute maximum” is the maximum voltage limit that
> the transceiver is allowed to see at any time. Any voltage above it would put the transceiver in an unsafe region
> of operation, and permanent damage could result.*

Vc of SM712, as specified in the datasheet:

[image]

Which makes SM712 clearly unsafe for this application.